# Calculating the relative error of a Euler method

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a forward Euler method to solve an ODE of a membrane evolution. I have two vectors, `X` and `Y`, storing the x- and y-values resp, and use the method in a for loop run `10^6`. Now, I want to calculate the relative error and stop the loop when this error is smaller than some chosen value. The relative error is given as

`|r^t - r^(t-1)|/|r^t|`

where `r^t` is a vector consisting of all the x- and y-values, at some time t. This is my solution

```
import numpy as np  

x0 = 2*np.pi*5/360/2 #resting membrane lengths
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, num=360, dtype=float)

X = (5 + 0.5*np.sin(20*phi))*np.cos(phi)
Y = (5 + 0.5*np.sin(20*phi))*np.sin(phi)

L = np.linspace(-1,358, num=360, dtype=int)
R = np.linspace(1,360, num=360,dtype=int) #right and left indexing vectors
R[359] = 0 #closed contour

ds = 1/360

r = np.hstack((X,Y)) #vector of X and Y
rt = np.zeros((10**5,720)) #r at time t

i = 0 

RE = 1 #relative error
e = 10**-10

while RE > e:
    
    lengths = np.sqrt( (X[R]-X)**2 + (Y[R]-Y)**2 )
    
    Ex = (1/10)/ds**2*(X[R] - 2*X + X[L] - x0*( (X[R]-X)/lengths - (X-X[L])/lengths[L]) )
    Ey = (1/10)/ds**2*(Y[R] - 2*Y + Y[L] - x0*( (Y[R]-Y)/lengths - (Y-Y[L])/lengths[L]) )
    
    X = X + e*Ex
    Y = Y + e*Ey
    
    r = np.hstack((X,Y))
    i = i + 1
    
    if i%10000000 ==0: #chooses time values to be multiples of 10^6
        rt[i] = r
        RE = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(rt[i]-rt[i-1],2)))/np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(rt[i],2)))
        print("RE=", RE)
        print(i)
```

However, the loop never ends. I get this error

`IndexError: index 100000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100000`

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code dies from undefined symbols.  You also haven't shown us the output trace.

Comment: I've changed the code so it should work now.I also added the error I get

Answer (score 0):

The "runs forever" problem is that you're running a very time-consuming loop: 10^7 iterations will run over two hours on my laptop.

The error is because you did not properly handle the indexing for your `rt` array.  You allocate only 10^5 rows, but you fill a row *only* when `i` is a multiple of 10^7 (not 10^6, as your comment states).  That's why the subscript is out of bounds: the first time you try to use it, it's too large.

Perhaps you need to increment `i` only when you recompute `RE`, not every iteration:

```
if i%10000000 ==0: #chooses time values to be multiples of 10^6
    i = i + 1
    rt[i] = r
    RE = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(rt[i]-rt[i-1],2))) /     \
         np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(rt[i],2)))
    print("RE=", RE)
    print(i)
```

Now, you *still* have to handle the initial condition.  The way you originally set this up, you increment `i` *past* a row of zeroes.  This *guarantees* that your division will fail, because the denominator is 0.  You have to code the first row before you get into this recomputation.